# Cannot understand this voice passage

Tags: listening

I can't understand the first thing Rukawa Kaede says in this video. My ears hear どう something but I'm not sure

https://youtu.be/O11z4aO7kYU

Thank you very much

Comment: We do not do transcriptions on this site.

Answer (score 2):

He is saying the slang word どあほ (ど阿呆) meaning "total idiot". 阿呆 means idiot and the ど adds emphasis.

https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E9%98%BF%E5%91%86

I searched it up and apparently it's some sort of iconic phrase from Slam Dunk.